# uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, typeerror

**Suddenly im getting error when i start ionic project**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
at Function.<anonymous> (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:115:26)
at Array.forEach (native)
at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\source-map\lib\sour
at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap] (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\source-map\lib
at SourceMapSource.node (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SourceMapSource.js:39:21)
at ReplaceSource.node (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ReplaceSource.js:70:30)
at CachedSource.node (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\CachedSource.js:18:24)
at D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:37:50
at Array.map (native)
at ConcatSource.node (D:\Work\Prince\TakeToTake\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:36:63)
```

[image: screen print of my terminal]

> Please Help

Comment: Fix the undefined variable on line 115 of `source-node.js`. We can't tell you more than that from what you've posted.

Comment: Nice errors.  No code, so no way to help.  Somewhere you have myvar.substr(...) and myvar isn't a string.

Comment: And how would we be able to help, when we have no idea what your code looks like?

Comment: james there are no code error  y error the occurring when i use "ionic serve " command

Comment: post output of of ionic info?

Comment: If you posted the code in question it might actually help

Comment: If you google `ionic cannot read property 'substr' of undefined` you'll find _several_ related links referring to what might be wrong. StackOverflow is not a "help me with someone elses program crashing" service but rather a "what is wrong with _my_ code, I'm trying to do X but Y is happening" site. Since you can't accept code changes as you didn't write this code we can't help you. Your problem is probably in a config file somewhere.

Comment: there is no any solution? any alternative solutions

Answer (score 0):

**Found the error**
i was implement two Component inside one TS file that's why  the nodeJS  confuse to run which component

now i created another ts file to implement the component

thanks for the comments